Want to build ESP project with a specific (Is there something like a multi-stage compiler?? XD)
I am working on a project with ESP32 and I use ESP-IDF to compile to compile the project.
Some files in my project cannot be shared with the whole team due to security reasons, so I want to have a workflow where they get something like a half compiled image (a build of the files they are not supposed to see) and then do another build on their end with rest of the files.
I am new to C++ and not an expert in the build system.
How can I do this?


Please explain why you think this is a site-valid electrical/electronic engineering question (rather one about code/person management and control).

I thought microcontroller firmware related queries could be posted here, they do have a firmware tag here

I believe the term you are looking for is static library

is there some reason you can't give them File_1.o, File_2.o and the .h files?  That's the usual way of hiding detail from one module to another.  (Though it's not clear what kind of security you're trying to achieve.)  The other method is to give dummy File_1.c etc, which allow some kind of integration and testing without giving away anything material.  You are like to get more detailed answers in a software Q+A than electronics.

Hey @TomCarpenter thanks, I looked up static libraries this was the sort of structure I was looking for, but would creating a static library file hide the contents of the library file when they are included in a file?

@jonathanjo sorry I am not much aware about the CPP compiler and am new to c++, I am aware the object files for all the files are created before all of those are linked to create a binary image but am not aware if it possible to build some part of the application into one object file and then while linking link the other file to it.
But yeah, now that we are getting into compilation part of things I think the questing belons to the software stack overflow. Should have understood what Andy wanted to say .

@Dojhoe Static libraries are basically fully compiled to machine code. While you can disassemble them (as you can any binary file), you can't get the original source code back from it. It's basically no different from giving the end user a fully compile program.

"due to security violations" Then an object file may not be safe enough, as it can be reverse-engineered. As can the downloaded code in the MCU.

@Dojhoe for some reason moderators closed your question saying it was "unclear or lacked details".  Personally I think it's perfectly clear, and I tried to get it reopened without success.  You can try on a software SE, but make sure you clarify it is for FIRMWARE on a microcontroller -- which many software developers don't understand well -- or you'll get lots of irrelevant things about dynamic libraries.  Your question really focuses on cmake, and how you tell it to use object files you don't have sources for; alternatively, how you make your own static libraries for ESP.

Your build process is already has the "multipart" compilation that you need.
The standard build process
The classical process compilers follow for making a single executable from multiple source files is

preprocess all .c with the .h files to make "pure" .c files (having dealt with all the #define, #include and similar),
compile each pure .c into a matching object .o file which contains machine code and enough information to link from one .o to another, and lastly
link all the .o information into an executable,   This is the process which allows a function in one file to call a function in another.  (Almost always with more .o-like material chosen from library files, for input, output, mathematical functions, sorting.)

You can see that this mechanism is exactly how you use, say, sprintf: your function knows how to call it from the definition in stdio.h, and the linker knows the addresses and so on in order to generate the actual jsr-type instructions.  You might never see the source.
Once you have the executable file it gets loaded onto the CPU, typically by flash programming, some kind of bootloader, or in a non-embedded system by the operating system.
The above process is the same whether the input is Pascal, Fortran, assembler, C, C++.  (Apart from filenames might be different and how .h files work is quite C-family specific.)
You can read an excellent description of all this at Stack Overflow answer.
Your problem
In the classic model, you might not have the source file of a given .o; you might not know the language, even.
In your case:

Privileged programmer writes and compiles File1.c and File2.c, which makes File1.o and File2.o.  You give these to the nonprivileged programmers, along with File1.h and File2.h
Nonprivileged program writes and compilers FileA.c and FileB.c, make makes FileA.o and FileB.o
Nonprivileged programmer links File1.o File2.o FileA.o FileB.o and whatever libraries are required
This makes your executable without showing File1.c or File2.c to the nonprivileged programmers
BUT if you don't trust the nonprivileged programmers with the executable, you can't trust them with the .o files either.

If the non-privileged coders are not allowed to have the executable, then you can give them dummy versions of the secret functions, with the same calling interface but without whatever is secret.  Where something like int isgoodpassword(char *username, char *password); is replaced with a version which does return strcmp(username, password) == 0; rather than whatever method you want to keep secret.  You give them fake versions of secret.h and secret.c and they build with those.

PS. About libraries

You can make your own library files and bundle some/all of the .o files into a library or libraries; perhaps all the confidential material into a single library.
The only real difference between a set of .o files and a library  is that you say which .o files you want ("Please build it with modules1.o, module2.o and module3.o"), whereas the linker decides which pieces of the libraries are wanted, and pulls them in automatically.  ("Ah, this program uses sort, I must find that in a library.")
In non-embedded systems, the libraries are usually now run-time libraries, which get linked when you start running the program; but you can still make static libraries if you want.  The principal advantage of dynamic libraries is it's easy to upgrade everything on a given system at the same time (say some cryptographic library with a bug fix) and it takes less space; the principal advantage of static libraries is that it you can test everything at link-time knowing it will be the same library as at run time, though it takes more space and requires bad versions in the field if you want to upgrade them.


Great answer! OP: keep in mind, that executables are not designed to keep secrets. It's just, that the others don't get to see the sourcecode but with some effort, it's possible to glean quite a lot from a compiled executable or library.
